# .htaccess redirection issue

Tags: .htaccess

I suck at htaccess and trying to achieve the following set of redirections. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I can't find anything on askapache and I don't understand general htaccess rules formating.

domain1.com/**x** -> sub.domain2.com (**x** being any page and file under this domain, but not the bare domain itself)

domain1.com -> domain2.com (when they type the bare domaine, redirect to the new one)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.htaccess can be used to modify behavior of any directory. Unless you set rule for /x to one directory, you can't use .htaccess. In this case it should be easier to set up redirection in Apache configuration file. Try something like this in Apache configuration file:

```
RewriteEngine   on
RewriteRule     ^/$     http://domain2.com/     [R,L]
RewriteRule     ^/.+    http://sub.domain2.com/ [R,L]
```